# How to handle exceptions with JDBC driver that does not support categorized exceptions?

Tags: jdbc, exception, jtds

The question is about JTDS but is also general enough to help other people find their way to.

Using the latest JTDS driver can't seem to find any docs, but does JTDS support Transasient, Non-Transasient and Recoverable exceptions?

It doesn't seems so but it seems that it supports SQL 92 state codes. Is there a general way to  detect if an exception is transient or non transient using just the state codes?

I know the list is here: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt But is there a way to categorize them or even maybe some db utils out there that do so?

Answer (score 0):

In my "realtime" service I will assume the following. Any SQL State starting with 08 (Connection errors) can be retried. All other states will be considered non recoverable.

I can assume this because my service accepts and process right away. The response is final, so if it's a failure we don't try to recover.